# Помогите больше понять про DataBinding Adapter. Не могу понять как получить данные из List

Tags: java, android, android-data-binding

Пытаюсь получить ссылку `"src"` на одно изображение из `List<Images>` используя `DataBinding`, но не могу до конца понять как. Без использования `DataBinding` получал ссылку на изображение в `onBindViewHolder` следующим образом:

`String imagePath = products.get(position).getImages().get(0).getSrc();`

Получаю следующую ошибку:

> Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.ImageView bind:mainImagePath>
> that accepts parameter type
> 'java.util.List<com.example.lafiores.model.product.Image>'
>
> If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is
> annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.

Мой код:

```
public class Product extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
private List<Image> images = null;

@BindingAdapter({"mainImagePath"})
public static void loadMainImage(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
    Glide
            .with(imageView)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageView);
}

@Bindable
public List<Image> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
    this.images = images;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.images);
}}
```

Класс Image

```
public class Image extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("src")
@Expose
private String src;

@Bindable
public String getSrc() {
    return src;
}

public void setSrc(String src) {
    this.src = src;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.src);
}}
```

Adapter

```
public class ListProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListProductAdapter.ListProductViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
private Application application;

public ListProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    this.context = context;
    this.products = products;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    ListProductItemBinding listProductItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
            R.layout.list_product_item,
            parent,
            false);

    return new ListProductViewHolder(listProductItemBinding);
}

public ListProductAdapter(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Product product = products.get(position);

    Product product = products.get(position);
    holder.listProductItemBinding.setProduct(product);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}


class ListProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ListProductItemBinding listProductItemBinding;


    public ListProductViewHolder(@NonNull ListProductItemBinding listProductItemBinding) {
        super(listProductItemBinding.getRoot());
        this.listProductItemBinding = listProductItemBinding;

        listProductItemBinding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailProductActivity.class);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

XML

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="product"
        type="com.example.lafiores.model.product.Product" />
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listProductItemImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            bind:mainImagePath="@{product.images}" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

UPDATE:

```
@BindingAdapter({"mainImagePath"})
public static void loadMainImage(ImageView imageView, List<Image> images) {
    Glide
            .with(imageView)
            .load(images.get(0).getSrc()) //вывожу первую картинку
            .into(imageView);
}

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listProductItemImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            bind:mainImagePath="@{product.images}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
@BindingAdapter({"mainImagePath"})
public static void loadMainImage(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
}
```

Согласно `@Bindable`, которая берется из декларации `ImageView` в xml - ожидается второй параметр в виде `List<Image>` - которой нет. Система ожидает что-то типа:

```
@BindingAdapter({"mainImagePath"})
public static void loadMainImage(ImageView imageView, List<Image> images) {
     //blah-blah
}
```

Либо вы такой сеттер нарисуйте, либо измените параметры bind'инга в xml

Comment: Получилось, скажите правильно ли так делать (добавил код, где внес исправления, после UPDATE)? я в глайде указал ссылку на нужный параметр src

Comment: Вроде правильно, только надо грамотно отработать вариант, когда массив пустой. И второе, непонятно зачем передавать массив и использовать только первый элемент массива - нелогично как то